# Why does my code run repeatedly when updating a search input, even though it's not connected to the state it's triggering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added a search input, but as I type something it seems that following code run again and again:

```js
const { list } = useList()
```

The search input doesn't do anything, it just updates the `searchValue` state and isn't even connected to `list` above.

I believe it rerenders the dom whenever I update the value of input.

```js
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState()

<Input
  value={searchValue}
  className="shadow-none"
  onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Here is how `useList` hook:

```
export default function useList() {
  let { data } = useQuery(GET_LIST)
  const list = _.cloneDeep(data)?.menuTree?.filter((i) => i.parentId === null) || []

  const otherMenus = data?.menuTree || []

  return { list, otherMenus }
}
```

I tried adding above searchInput in a separate component, but it doesn't help!

How to I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like react is working as designed. Any time a component's state is changed (such as when you call `setSearchValue`) react calls the component function again to find out what the new output html should be.

If you want something to happen just once (when the component is initialized), you want to do something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //do stuff on component init
}, [])
```